# Concat a php variable in a json line

Tags: php, string, json, variables, concatenation

I have the following in myfile.php

```
$json_data = '{"type":"email","msg":"some text"}';
```

Instead of typing "email" or "some text" I want to concat the php variables $thetype and $themsg to the line before.

How can I do that? No matter what I do I get a syntax error.

I'm trying:

```
$json_data = '{"type":"+$thetype+","msg":"+$themsg+"}';
```

But as I say errors galore.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your question is a little vague...

Are you looking for this?

```
$json = array('type' => $thetype, 'msg' => $themsg);
$json_data = json_encode($json);
```

That will set `$json_data` to a string like what you described:

```
<?php

$thetype = 'something';
$themsg = 'something else';
$json = array('type' => $thetype, 'msg' => $themsg);
$json_data = json_encode($json);
var_dump($json_data);
```

Would print:

```
string(43) "{"type":"something","msg":"something else"}"
```

See [the PHP manual for json_encode](http://php.net/json_encode).

You could try and build the string by hand, like this:

```
$json_data = '{"type":"'. addcslashes($thetype,"\"'\n").'","msg":"'. addcslashes($themsg,"\"'\n").'"}';
```

But, you'll generally be better off using json_encode, as it's designed for this purpose and is much less likely to produce invalid JSON.

Comment: Is it possible to do anything like: $json_data = '{"type":"+$thetype+","msg":"+$themsg+"}';?

Comment: @user523129 Possible, yes. But not advisable. Using Josh's solution, you can be sure to get a correctly formated json string. Otherwise you can easily break the result. E.g. using `$thetype = 'break " me';`

Comment: It is possible, though it's just wrong. In either case, you have to encode data for JSON. In example provided by @Josh, you do it once on the whole array. If you want to do it "your way", you have to do it twice - `$jsonType = json_encode($theType); $jsonMsg = json_encode($theMsg); $jsonData = "{\"type\":{$jsonType},\"msg\":{$jsonMsg}}";` - this is **wrong** as you have to both call `json_encode()` multiple times and have to manually build a string that is hard to read and modify.

Comment: You could... I edited my answer to show how. But this is what `json_encode` is designed for

Comment: @Josh, what about multi-line strings (with unescaped newline characters)? Does JSON accept them?

Comment: @binaryLV: are you asking is `json_encode` accepts them? It sure does! It will accept arrays, objects, and other complicated structures. http://us2.php.net/json_encode

Comment: No, I'm asking if manually built JSON string with newline in it is valid or not. When there's a newline in JSON string, `json_decode()` fails with `JSON_ERROR_SYNTAX`. That's one of reasons why `json_encode()` should be used instead of trying to build JSON string manually.

Comment: @binaryLV No, if you manually build the string, you will need to properly escape all of those using `addcslashes` or an equivalent, which is why `json_encode` is much better.

Comment: Ahh, that's some *advanced* `addcslashes()` being used there... Didn't notice that it escapes newlines.

Comment: @binaryLV I had addcslashes wrong at first. It takes two parameters, I had forgotten the second one which is a list of characters to escape. **My example list above is nowhere near complete for valid JSON!!!**

Answer (score -1):

PHP has a function to encode json.
HOWEVER you need to output it as an object to save the keys.
This is a 3D array by the way.

```
$data[]=array('type' => $thetype0, 'msg' => $themsg0);
$data[]=array('type' => $thetype1, 'msg' => $themsg1);
$json=json_encode((object)$data);
```

EDIT: This method should be used for OLDER PHP versions. It is compatible with PHP 5.3.
The json_encode() function has several changes to it that makes it so the object output isnt available in PHP 5.2.

Comment: Don't forget the `JSON_FORCE_OBJECT` option.

Comment: -1, This isn't what he's asking... Also, you don't need to convert it to a object